# Android libGDX crashes randomly on startup

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, libgdx

It seems the `InputProcessor` is trying to run before the entire program is finished initializing.

How can I delay the `InputProcessor` ?

because I am randomly getting `NullPointerExceptions` when I first launch the program because the `touchdown` event is being triggered in the middle of the program loading (it only takes 2 seconds for the program to start up).

I have 2 threads start up so I think I might need to pause in the middle of my `create()` method until the 2 threads have finished initializing their variables.

"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

desired behavior: my create thread to wait for my other 2 threads to finish is how I am thinking this problem will be resolved.

Here is a little diagram of my code

```
//create thread 1
//create thread 2
//initialize variables
//initialize InputProcessor
//infinite while loop

//helper thread 1
//initialize some variables
//infinite while loop

//helper thread 2
//initialize some variables
//infinite while loop
```

the problem is the create thread has an input that seems to take input even before the program is finished launching. This glitch only happens within the first second of launching occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use a shared 
[AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) between the thread to signal that `InputProcessor` is safe to initialize.

<s>Or you could use [Thread.join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) to wait for the thread completion in the main thread.</s>

<s>It would be difficult to give further answer without seeing some minimal code.</s>

**Update** :

According to your diagram sequence, The `main thread` hold reference to `thread_1` and `thread_2`, each of these thread instance could have an AtomicBoolean value, the `main thread` could check both in a loop before continuing on the initialization.

Or you could also use `Condition variable`( [android specific](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ConditionVariable.html) or [java](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) ), to blick the `main thread` until the child thread init is done.

Comment: where is `InputProcessor` initialized, and where are the Threads started ?

Comment: the helper threads are created in the beginning of the create constructor and the InputProcessor is initialized and set for libGDX at the bottom of the create constructor. So usually it is not a problem since the two threads are done getting set up before it even reaches the InputProcessor usually.